# INSERT INTO within an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

In an Oracle stored procedure, can you have an INSERT INTO immediately after opening a cursor?

**I get this message:**

```
    Error(9,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of 
the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with <an identifier>    
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>   
 continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date 
<a string literal with character set specification>    
<a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    
<an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
```

**On the 3rd line of the following:**

```
   BEGIN

   OPEN GRSREFVALUES FOR

   --Select REFERENCEVALUES of Unprocessed Variations

INSERT INTO l_data (value)

   SELECT REFERENCEVALUE
```

Comment: You can't use a cursor for an insert (and you don't need to anyway). Just remove the `open ... for` part.

Comment: So I could do the insert to get the data in to the table, then open a cursor to select from that table?

Comment: Maybe if you were to explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Of course, 3 things to happen: INSERT to get the data into a particular table, then open a cursor and select from a 2nd table (these 2 steps now ok thanks to the previous comment) then lastly perform an update on the 2nd table.

Comment: In fact it all seems fine now, thanks for you time!